# Less Than Overload C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

```
struct nodeStructType {
    char letter;
    int count;
};

struct node {
    nodeStructType data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    bool operator <(const node* comp)
    {
        return data.letter < comp->data.letter;
    }

};

typedef node* nodePtr;
```

Hi! I'm working on a project and am overloading the < operator like this.
However, when calling

```
a = myTree.GetANode('a', 0);
b = myTree.GetANode('b', 0);

    if (a < b)
    {
        printf("yay!");
    }
```

, a and b both being nodePtr's, it is not returning true.
GetANode function just sets data.letter to 'a' and 'b'

Comment: Can you show how you are calling it?

Comment: You have overloaded `node < node*`

Comment: Edited to show how its called -- Why would overloading node < node* be an issue? Since I am dereferencing the node* when comparing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the operator like

```
struct node {
    nodeStructType data;
    node* left;
    node* right;

    bool operator <(const node &comp) const
    {
        return data.letter < comp.data.letter;
    }

};
```

And call it like

```
if ( *a < *b)
{
    printf("yay!");
}
```

Or

```
if ( a->operator <( *b ) )
{
    printf("yay!");
}
```

Otherwise in this if statement

```
if (a < b)
{
    printf("yay!");
}
```

there are compared two pointers and your operator is not called.

Comment: Thanks, changing my operator declaration to yours and dereferencing my comparators solved this.